# Xpath - grabbing each line separately that used BR tags

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="school_row_cell_content">
<div class="center_div">
    <img src="/assets/isbiimages/c1504.jpg" alt="School Crest" width="190"></div>
                 Shelburne Road,
<br class="">Cheltenham,
<br class="">Gloucestershire,
<br class="">United Kingdom,
<br class="">GL51 6HE
<br class="">
<br class=""><strong>Tel:</strong> +44 1242 258000
<br class=""><strong>Fax:</strong> +44 1242 258004
<br class=""><br class=""><strong><a href="http://www.deanclose.org.uk" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" id="154" title="opens in new window" class="school_website_btn">Visit School Website</a></strong>
<br class="">
<br class=""><strong>Founded:</strong>1886<br class=""><br class=""><strong>Headmaster:</strong>
<br class=""><a href="/assets/isbiimages/ph1504.jpg" class="iframe_popups">Mr Bradley Salisbury</a>
<br class=""><br class=""><strong>Registrar:</strong>
<br class="">Mrs Kelly Serjeant
<br class="">
<br class="">This school offers flexi-boarding.
<br class="">
<br class=""><strong>Accreditations and affiliations:</strong>
<br class="">ISBA, HMC, BSA, AGBIS
<br class=""><strong>Religious affiliation:</strong>
<br class="">Church of England<br class=""><strong>Teaching languages:</strong>
<br class="">English
<br class="">                                           
</div>
```

I want to grab each line of this information separately but as there are only br tags I am struggling to do this. Especially given the classes are empty. I am trying this type of thing:

```
//div[@class='school_row_cell_content']/@br
//div[@class='school_row_cell_content']/br[@class=''][1]
```

but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to isolate a `br` node first, then get the preceding or following text node. So to get the text node containing "Shelburne Road":

```
//div[@class='school_row_cell_content']/br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

To get the text node containing "Cheltenham":

```
//div[@class='school_row_cell_content']/br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

To get the text node containing "Gloucestershire":

```
//div[@class='school_row_cell_content']/br[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```